# Software Updates UI stuck in a loop

Tags: apt, update-manager

I am witnessing a uncommon behavior of Software Update interface (i.e. the software "Software" in the unity menu) 
Namely, it keeps telling me to update the bios of my Thinkpad from 0.1.17 to 0.1.18 even if apt-get and apt have everything up-to-date.

Obviously, doing the update by clicking "Update All" just reboot the computer without doing nothing. 
Is there a way to clean the cache of the graphical interface of the software updates package or something similar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest BIOS manually from Lenovo site. If that fails, then try forcing a reset on your computer by holding down the power button for 5 to 15 seconds. Otherwise, try reinstalling the OS. I know of no actual way to clear the cache of a system app, but that does not mean 
it does not exist. There may be another solution from a root terminal, but that can get tricky.

Comment: but I think I have already the latest BIOS, it is just the user intarface that is unable to understand it..